# Increase expiration of NextToken in DynamoDB ExecuteStatement

Tags: go, pagination, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go, partiql

We have an API that reads the data from DynamoDB by using PartiQL query in `ExecuteStatementWithContext` function. This API is paginated and i rely on NextToken for reading all DynamoDB pages.

The problem is that there is an expiry for NextToken and i am getting this error `ValidationException: Given NextToken has already expired`. Can we increase this expiry in any way?